# Unable to print out information

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, output

I am writing a program which stores students' information (ID, name, major, cpa and assessment). When I compile it, there is no errors and it runs smoothly until outputting the result after inputting the information successfully. When I debug, I'm sure that the information has been successfully inserted and the error is in the `display` function. I really need your help to figure out what the error is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    string student_id;
    string name;
    string major;
    float gpa;
    char assessment;
    Student()
    {
        student_id = "";
        name = "";
        major = "";
        gpa = 0.0;
        assessment = 'F';
    }
    void addinfo(string id, string student_name, string student_major, float student_gpa)
    {
        this->student_id = id;
        this->name = student_name;
        this->major = student_major;
        this->gpa = student_gpa;
    }
    char assessstudent()
    {
        if (this->gpa >= 8.0)
            return 'A';
        if (this->gpa < 8.0 && this->gpa >= 6.0)
            return 'B';
        if (this->gpa < 6.0 && this->gpa >= 4.0)
            return 'C';
        if (this->gpa < 4.0 && this->gpa >= 2.0)
            return 'D';
        if (this->gpa < 2.0)
            return 'F';
    }
};

void swap(float* a, float* b)
{
    float temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void sortwithgrade(Student* array, int r, int l)
{
    float temp = array[r].gpa;
    int m = (r + l) / 2;
    int i = l+1;
    int j = r ;
    if (r > l)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            while (array[++i].gpa <= temp)
                ;
            while (array[--j].gpa >= temp)
                ;
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            swap(array[i], array[j]);
        }
        swap(array[i], array[r]);
        sortwithgrade(array, l, m - 1);
        sortwithgrade(array, m + 1, r);
    }
}
void display(Student* array, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", "Student ID", "Student name", "Student Major", "Student gpa", "Student Assess");
    while (i != max)
    {
        printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20.2f%c\n", array[i].student_id, array[i].name, array[i].major, array[i].gpa, array[i].assessment);
        i++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Student list[10];
    cout << "How many students do you want to add?\n";
    int max;
    cin >> max;
    getchar();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student number " << i << endl;
        cout << "ID: ";
        string stdid;
        getline(cin, stdid);
        cout << "Name: ";
        string stdname;
        getline(cin, stdname);
        cout << "Major: ";
        string stdmajor;
        getline(cin, stdmajor);
        cout << "GPA: ";
        float gpa;
        cin >> gpa;
        getchar();
        list[i].addinfo(stdid, stdname, stdmajor, gpa);
        char stdassess = list[i].assessstudent();
        list[i].assessment = stdassess;
    }
    sortwithgrade(list, 0, max - 1);
    display(list, max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use %s for c++ `string`s. You should ideally use C++ style output (e.g. `std::cout`) or if you really want to keep using printf then add `.c_str()` to get the raw c-style string

Comment: @MikeVine I'm sorry but where do I put ``.c_str``?

Comment: There is a reason why `printf()` is not recommended to use in C++ and you hit it.

Comment: `printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20.2f%c\n", array[i].student_id.c_str(), array[i].name.c_str(), array[i].major.c_str(), array[i].gpa, array[i].assessment);`

Comment: BTW, you only need to use `this->` to differentiate between method parameters and class members.